# Get request replace with ajax url

Tags: ajax

how to find the get() request URL send to the server when the URL is replace with the different url which in turn gives the results from cache

for example

I access the website below

https://apps.belairdirect.com/quick-quote/desktop/index.html?prov=on&lang=en&intcid=homepage#s1

and fill the form and send the request to the server

The url changes to the below url

https://apps.belairdirect.com/quick-quote/desktop/index.html?prov=on&lang=en&intcid=homepage#s2

I want the actual get() request url that was send to the server. like in case of google the request is in the url changing the url changes the request

Comment: HUH? So they update the hash? Look at the network request in the developer tools.

Comment: In the developer tools it does has the url, but when tried to access it has the

Comment: the ..... what is the request of the thought?

Comment: In the developer tools it does has the url in the xhr, but when tried to access it has the error with xml. the redirecting page is not written, it returns json object

Comment: the page is not return it directs to the xml i.e json

Comment: <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<env:Body>
<env:Fault>
<faultcode>env:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>Internal Error</faultstring>
</env:Fault>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>

Comment: So the XML is what the URL returns. Either that is what the server is returning with the Ajax call or you are not making a POST/PUT request like the Ajax call is. I can not really help you out without seeing it.